# How to create dropdown navigation using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I tried creating a dropdown list that is visible when you hover over the link.

I want to create a navigation menu that drops links when hover over the link using jQuery.

I created a function such that when you hover over **'link 3'** the dropdown will fall (using *mouseenter* and *mouseleave*). But when you move the mouse over the dropdown link it **should** remain the same but it is going up.

Also is it possible to force hover state on link 3 when you hover over the dropdown contents?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div#header ul li a#link-three").on('mouseenter', function(){
  $("div#header-dropdown-content").slideDown(500);
 });
 
 $("div#header ul li a#link-three").on('mouseleave', function(){
  $("div#header-dropdown-content").slideUp(500);
 });
 
 $("div#header-dropdown-content a").on('mouseenter', function(){
  $("div#header-dropdown-content").slideDown(500);
  $("a#link-three").trigger('hover');
 });
 
 $("div#header-dropdown-content a").on('mouseleave', function(){
  $("div#header-dropdown-content").slideUp(500);
 });
});
```

```css
div#header {
 z-index: 1;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
div#header ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 user-select: none;
 font-size: 1.15em;
 margin: -8px;
 padding: 0;
 height: 43px;
 overflow: hidden;
 backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
 background: none;
 background-color: rgba(23 23 23 / 75%);
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0 0 0 / 60%);
}
div#header ul li {
 float: left;
}
div#header ul li a {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 6px 16px;
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .5s border-bottom, .3s background;
}
div#header ul li a:hover {
 background: #222;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #f00;
}

div#header-dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 114.5px;
 top: 43px;
 font-size: 17px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px #aaa;
 background: #f1f1f1;
 width: 157.5px;
}
div#header-dropdown-content a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: flex;
 padding: 15px 10px;
}
div#header-dropdown-content a:hover {background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link-one">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link-two">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link-three">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="header-dropdown-content">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 1</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 2</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 3</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 4</a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Your script would produce an error, due to `div#header ul li a#` not being a valid selector. Furthermore, your script references a `<div>` element with `id` `header-languages-content` but this is not presented in your HTML. consider providing code that represents your problem.

Comment: I have edited the question... Please check n suggest any solution. Thanks

Comment: Why use jQuery or even elementary Javascript if you can do that with just CSS?

Comment: Can you show how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider having some state variables that check whether the dropdown or the link is hovered. Show if either is `true` or hide if both are `false`.

Since there is a slight gap between the hitbox of the link and the dropdown, have a delay before checking whether the dropdown should hide. This gives time for the user to move their mouse to the dropdown.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let linkHovered = false;
  let dropdownHovered = false;
  let timeout;
  
  const check = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    if (linkHovered || dropdownHovered) {
      $("div#header-dropdown-content").slideDown(500);
    }
    else {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!linkHovered && !dropdownHovered) {
          $("div#header-dropdown-content").slideUp(500);
        }
      }, 200);
    }
  };

 $("div#header ul li a#link-three").on('mouseenter', function(){
   linkHovered = true;
   check();
 });
 
 $("div#header ul li a#link-three").on('mouseleave', function(event) {
   linkHovered = false;
   check();
 });
 
 $("div#header-dropdown-content a").on('mouseenter', function(){
   dropdownHovered = true;
   check();
 });
 
 $("div#header-dropdown-content a").on('mouseleave', function(){
   dropdownHovered = false;
   check();
 });
});
```

```css
div#header {
 z-index: 1;
 position: sticky;
 top: 0;
}
div#header ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 user-select: none;
 font-size: 1.15em;
 margin: -8px;
 padding: 0;
 height: 43px;
 overflow: hidden;
 backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
 background: none;
 background-color: rgba(23 23 23 / 75%);
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0 0 0 / 60%);
}
div#header ul li {
 float: left;
}
div#header ul li a {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 6px 16px;
 border: 4px solid transparent;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: .5s border-bottom, .3s background;
}
div#header ul li a:hover {
 background: #222;
 border-bottom: 4px solid #f00;
}

div#header-dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 left: 114.5px;
 top: 43px;
 font-size: 17px;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px #aaa;
 background: #f1f1f1;
 width: 157.5px;
}
div#header-dropdown-content a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: flex;
 padding: 15px 10px;
}
div#header-dropdown-content a:hover {background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link-one">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link-two">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link-three">Link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="header-dropdown-content">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 1</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 2</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 3</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);">Dropdown 4</a>
</div>

</body>
```